# Shiny app: Keep panels consistent in several views

Tags: r, shiny

In Shiny I want to keep some panels (panel1 below) consistent in several views (Plotview 1 and 2 below).

Below I am able to show panel1 in Plotview2 – but, the panel does not work in this view.

(The goal is to be able to have a few "panels" consistent through several "Plotviews" – and a few specific "panels" for some "Plotviews".)

```
library(shiny)

# Example panels
panel1 <- tabPanel("Panel 1",
                   radioButtons(inputId = "alt1",
                                      label = "Select:",
                                      choices = c(
                                        "A" = "A",
                                        "B" = "B"),
                                      selected = "A"))

panel2 <- tabPanel("Panel 2",
                   radioButtons(inputId = "alt2",
                                      label = "Select:",
                                      choices = c(
                                        "C" = "C",
                                        "D" = "D"),
                                      selected = "C"))
# UI
ui <-
  navbarPage(title = "Panel 1-2",
             collapsible = TRUE,
             fluid = TRUE,

             # tab 1
             tabPanel("Plotview 1",
                      fluidRow(
                        column(3,
                               tabsetPanel(type = "pills",
                                           panel1)),

                        # Main panel 1
                        mainPanel(fluidRow(
                          plotOutput("plot1"))
                        ))),

             # tab panel 2
             tabPanel("Plotview 2",
                      fluidRow(
                        column(3,
                               tabsetPanel(type = "pills",
                                           panel1,
                                           panel2,
                                           selected = "Panel 2")),

                        # Main panel 2
                        mainPanel(plotOutput("plot2"))
                        )))

## server
server <- function(input, output) {

  # Example plot 1
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    if (input$alt1[1] == "A") data <- iris$Sepal.Length
    if (input$alt1[1] == "B") data <- iris$Sepal.Width

    hist(data)
  })

  # Example plot 2
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({

    if (input$alt1[1] == "A") data <- iris$Sepal.Length
    if (input$alt1[1] == "B") data <- iris$Sepal.Width

    if (input$alt2[1] == "C") brk <- 2
    if (input$alt2[1] == "D") brk <- 4

    hist(data, breaks = brk)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In panel 1, A is select.
[image]

In panel 1, A is not selected anymore.
[image]
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, reusing UI elements as done with `panel1` in your example code is [not allowed in HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_id.asp#:%7E:text=The%20id%20attribute%20specifies%20a,element%20with%20the%20specific%20id.):

> The value of the id attribute must be unique within the HTML document.

I'd suggest to keep things simple and avoid creating the tabPanels as child elements of the `navbarPage`. As @bmrn mentioned this could be done using shiny's `?sidebarLayout`.

However, I assume you'd like to keep the layout as it is. To achive this we can add a `style` parameter to the `tabsetPanel` via `tagAppendAttributes` and cover a part of the `navbarPage`.

Furthermore, please note the `observeEvent` to control the tab visibility:

```
ui <- div(tagAppendAttributes(tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Panel 1", br(),
                                                   radioButtons(inputId = "alt1",
                                                                label = "Select:",
                                                                choices = c(
                                                                  "A" = "A",
                                                                  "B" = "B"),
                                                                selected = "A")),
                                          tabPanel("Panel 2", br(),
                                                   radioButtons(inputId = "alt2",
                                                                label = "Select:",
                                                                choices = c(
                                                                  "C" = "C",
                                                                  "D" = "D"),
                                                                selected = "C")),
                                          id = "tabsetPanelID",
                                          type = "pills"), style = "position:absolute; top:70px; left:15px; z-index:1;"),
          navbarPage(title = "Panel 1-2",
                     tabPanel("Plotview 1",
                              fluidRow(
                                column(11, plotOutput("plot1"), offset = 1)
                              )),
                     tabPanel("Plotview 2",
                              fluidRow(
                                column(11, plotOutput("plot2"), offset = 1)
                              )),
                     id = "navbarID",
                     collapsible = TRUE,
                     fluid = TRUE))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$navbarID, {
    if(input$navbarID == "Plotview 1"){
      hideTab(inputId = "tabsetPanelID", target = "Panel 2")
    } else {
      showTab(inputId = "tabsetPanelID", target = "Panel 2")
    }
  })
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    if (input$alt1[1] == "A") data <- iris$Sepal.Length
    if (input$alt1[1] == "B") data <- iris$Sepal.Width
    hist(data)
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    if (input$alt1[1] == "A") data <- iris$Sepal.Length
    if (input$alt1[1] == "B") data <- iris$Sepal.Width
    if (input$alt2[1] == "C") brk <- 2
    if (input$alt2[1] == "D") brk <- 4
    hist(data, breaks = brk)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example you have defined `panel1` once, outside of the `server` and `ui` definitions and then reused it in two places in the ui. Even though this means that you (problematically) have two elements with the same inputId, these elements will not behave as if they are related.

This does not answer your question, but one solution to your problem is to place a single instance of `panel1` in a sidebar that is visible regardless of the selected tab. I won't illustrate that here but it should be straight forward.

A method that better answers your question is to define a new `panel1` element for each time you would like it to appear in the ui. An easy way to do this is to rewrite you definition as a function that passes an `inputId` to `radioButtons()`:

```
panel1 <- function(id) {
  tabPanel("Panel 1",
           radioButtons(inputId = id,
                        label = "Select:",
                        choices = c(
                          "A" = "A",
                          "B" = "B"),
                        selected = "A"))
}
```

Now `panel1("alt1")` returns your original definition of `panel1`.

Pass a different `id` each time you call `panel1()`.

```
# tab 1
tabPanel("Plotview 1",
         fluidRow(
           column(3,
                  tabsetPanel(type = "pills",
                              panel1("alt1"))), # original panel1
           
           # Main panel 1
           mainPanel(fluidRow(
             plotOutput("plot1"))
           ))),

# tab panel 2
tabPanel("Plotview 2",
         fluidRow(
           column(3,
                  tabsetPanel(type = "pills",
                              panel1("alt1_child1"), # 2nd panel1 w/ new id
                              panel1("alt1_child2"), # 3rd panel1 w/ new id
                              panel2,
                              selected = "Panel 2")),

#... other ui code
```

To illustrate that this can be extended beyond just two instances I have added two instances of the radio buttons in the second tab.

Now in `server`, we need to tell shiny to update change all of the instances of `panel1`, whenever the user makes a change to one instance. An easy way to think about this is two think of one instance as the main instance and the others as child instances.

Use `observe()` to watch for changes to a `input` element and `updateRadioButtons()` to reflect those changes in other instances of `panel1`.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

# one observe statement for each set of radio buttons
# when input$alt1_child[1/2] changes, alt1 will be updated to match

observe({
  updateRadioButtons(inputId = "alt1", selected = input$alt1_child1)
})
observe({
  updateRadioButtons(inputId = "alt1", selected = input$alt1_child2)
})

# an update to input$alt1 will be reflected in all child instances
observe({
  in1 <- input$alt1
  updateRadioButtons(inputId = "alt1_child1", selected = in1)
  updateRadioButtons(inputId = "alt1_child2", selected = in1)
})

#... other server code

}
```

A change in the main instance should cause all child instances to change, and a change in any child instance should cause the main instance to change. The relationship between each pair of child instances is not important, since a change to one will change the main instance, which will in turn change all child instances.